# Printing Output before getting recursion value

Tags: php, recursion, echo

The output of the following is `1102555`. How is it possible? Does recursion takes place first or echo?

```
abc(11);
function abc($a){       
    if(intval($a/2) != 0){      
         echo  abc(intval($a/2)) + 10 *  ($a/2);        
    }else{
        echo 1;         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case , recursion will take place first, because everytime you call the function abc with $a/2 greater than 0, the abc() in the echo gets called again and again till the value of $a/2 is less than 0.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is first in this case. Expression is evaluated from inner most to outer. So in this case it's something like this:

1. $a/2
2. intval(RESULT_OF_PREVIOUS_HERE)
3. abc(RESULT_OF_PREVIOUS_HERE
4. $a/2
5. 10 * (RESULT_OF_PREVIOUS_HERE)
6. echo RESULT_OF_PREVIOUS_HERE